How to use variable inside fixture that will be set in a test file
I am struggling to see how can a use a variable inside a fixture that will be set inside a test. Let me show you with "code" what I mean:
Here is the fixture I want to use with useridentifier and userpassword my variables in the conftest.py file :
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def role_user(set_up,useridentifier,userpassword):
    page = set_up
    page.get_by_test_id("identifier").fill(useridentifier)
    page.get_by_test_id("password").fill(userpassword)
    page.get_by_test_id("submit").click()

    yield page

and here the test function in my test_login.py file:
def test_login(role_user,"username","password") -> None:
    page = role_user
    expect(page.get_by_role("cell", name="Identifier")).to_be_visible()


How can I use identifier and password as variable?

Just create their fixtures which return them as a string.
